# ClosedXML Pivot Tables Only Render After Enable Editing

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, openxml, closedxml

I'm using ClosedXML to create a spreadsheet with a pivot table.  I built a C# WinForm application that creates the file on my C:\ drive.

When I open the file after creating it, I get a warning at the top of Excel stating:

> PROTECTED VIEW: Be careful - files from the Internet can contain...

followed by a button that reads, "Enable Editing".

If I do not enable editing, then the pivot table doesn't appear on the sheet; just a single blue cell where the beginning of the pivot table should be appears.

If I close Excel and reopen the same file and click the "Enable Editing" button, Excel flickers and then the pivot table renders as expected.

Is there anything I can do with either OpenXML or ClosedXML to avoid this added step?

Our previous method of generating spreadsheets used Excel ActiveX objects to build the spreadsheets and those don't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Excel / Office mechanism to verify if a document is coming from an untrusted source is checking the file path of the file Excel is trying to open. If a file is deemed untrusted it blocks most potential harmful features, including rendering pivot tables.

When the file is located in an by the system deemed unsafe path Excel will give you that protected view warning. Common paths for which this is true include the C:\Temp, the C:\Windows\Temp, the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp and the Download folder of your browser.

To prevent this from happening save your file in a regular folder that belongs to the user, for example Documents or Desktop.

You can use this call to `GetFolderPath` to easily get a folder to such a trusted location:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
```

Once saved there the protection warning will be gone.

Answer (score -1):

ClosedXML doesn't implement pivot table rendering yet.